# sendKeys() not working using wire protocol in chromedriver for date input

Tags: java, android, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i am trying to execute a test case from java using ChromeDriver and executing json wire protocol. So far i was able to run my test case easily but now i am facing the issue while sending text on input tag type date.

I am able to find the element on the page. Even sending text event using this [***sendKeys***](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/:sessionId/element/:id/value) protocol return success result code 0 but the text string is nowhere found on that input element.

code snippet:

```
...
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("value", values.toCharArray());
String json = Util.executeRequest(Util.buildUri(Constants.METHOD_SEND_KEYS, params),
RequestMethod.POST, jsonObject);
JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(json);
if(Integer.parseInt(responseObj.get("status").toString()) != 0){
    ExceptionManager.parseException(Integer.parseInt(responseObj.get("status").toString()), new JSONObject(responseObj.get("value").toString()).get("message").toString());
}
```

Util.executeRequest

```
...
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
if(body!=null){
    HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(body.toString());
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);                     
}
response = client.execute(httpPost);
json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

I've tried with chromedriver version 2.9, 2.14, 2.15 but i don't seems to find issues with version. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have a similar problem, some (first) of ca. 20 chars are posted, but not every one. Number of posted chars differs from one run to another...

Comment: Currently the workaround that i am using for this is executing JS to set the value for date input.